# how to controll hibernate lazy loading exception

Tags: hibernate, exception, lazy-loading

I am using **Hibernate and Struts**

we are using lazy loading in hibernate.

now in JSP I am facing the lazy loading exception, the other solution is that to use EAGER, but I can not change to Eager dependency of other applications.

focusing on lazy loading any way to control lazy loading exception?

Answer (score 1):

The default loading strategy is to use `LAZY` fetching for associated collections. And the recommended solution is to load the associated collections by overriding this default strategy at runtime in code. Both the `Query` and `Criteria` interfaces support this.

For example, if you have below entity association mapping:

```
public class XEntity {
...
private Set<YEntity> yentities;
}
}
```

then with `Query` interface, the associated `yentities` can be fetched along with the `XEntity` as this:

```
String xSelect = "select x from XEntity "
                + "x left join fetch x.yentities "
                + "where x.xName=:xname";
Query query = session.createQuery(xSelect);
```

and with `Criteria` interface, this can be done as this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(XEntity.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("yentities", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

Both of these two will fetch the associated `yentities` along with the `XEntity`, in a single select.

You can also use [Hibernate#initialize](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize%28java.lang.Object%29) to initialize the collection:

```
XEntity xentity = (XEntity) session.get(XEntity.class, id);
Hibernate.initialize(xentity.getYentities());
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

But its a good practice to fetch the complete required graph in the first place, using `HQL` or `Criteria` queries.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to avoid lazy loading exceptions is to use fetch joins. If you have an entity `Employee` with lazily loaded attribute `projects`, you would rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN FETCH e.projects
```

You probably want to use a `LEFT JOIN` here to get all Employees, with or without projects. A simple `JOIN FETCH` would result in an inner join, returning only employees with projects.

A different, less explicit way to trigger loading of lazily loaded attributes is to access them before the transaction commits:

```
tx.begin(); // for illustration, also works for container managed transactions  
...
Employee emp = // get the employee
emp.getProjects().size();
...
tx.commit();
```

Please note that it would not be enough to call `emp.getProjects()` to trigger loading. You actually need to perform an operation that needs the value of the attribute to trigger loading.

I would generally prefer the first approach because it communicates the intent much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use transaction manager in hibernate and @NotFound annotation.

```
@Entity
public class OurEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department")
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private LazyObject lazyObject;

    // ... getters, setters

}

public class SomeOtherClass {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public LazyObject getSomethingLazy(Long id){

     final OurEntity ourEntity = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(OurEntity.class, id);
     LazyObject lazyObject = null;
     if(ourEntity != null){
         //this will never throw lazy loading exception if Transactional annotation is used
         lazyObject = ourEntity.getLazyObject();
     }
     return lazyObject;
}
```

and configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   <property name="driverClass"><value>${public.jdbc.driverClassName}</value></property>
   <property name="jdbcUrl"><value>${public.jdbc.url}</value></property>
   <property name="username"><value>${public.jdbc.username}</value></property>
   <property name="password"><value>${public.jdbc.password}</value></property>

   <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60"/>
   <property name="idleMaxAge" value="240"/>
   <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="1"/>
   <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="1"/>
   <property name="partitionCount" value="3"/>
   <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"/>
   <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100"/>
   <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>packages.to.scan</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">DATABASE.DIALECT.CLASS.PATH</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--Transaction management -->
<bean id="transactionTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
<bean id="transactionManagerPublic" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```